# Why does strip.white work when trimws does not?

Tags: r

I am reading in a .csv that NA observations are recorded as "-   ".

```
returns <-read.csv("~/R/ADFG_Obtained_AKReturns.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(returns)

'data.frame':   4222 obs. of  15 variables:
$ Year            : int  1975 1976 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1978 1978 1978 ...
$ Region          : chr  "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Prince William Sound" ...
$ Hatchery        : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "AF Koernig" 
...
 $ Project         : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Port San 
Juan" ...
 $ Species         : chr  "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" ...
 $ Seine           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " 2,000 " ...
 $ Gillnet         : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ Troll           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ Other.Commercial: chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ Sport           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ PersUse         : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ Subsis          : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
 $ Brood           : chr  " 5,800 " " 8,000 " " -   " " 21,300 " ...
 $ CR.catch        : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " 15,545 " ...
 $ Other           : chr  " -   " " -   " " 18,500 " " -   " ...
```

When I read in the .csv then attempt to trimws, the white spaces are not removed (the df does not change at all. This was first attempted by the suggestion of my colleagues' reformatting process). Note that in the below code I used "both", but I've attempted "right" with the same results.

```
returns <-read.csv("~/R/ADFG_Obtained_AKReturns.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
returns <- trimws(returns, which = c("both"))
str(returns)

'data.frame':   4222 obs. of  15 variables:
$ Year            : int  1975 1976 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1978 1978 
1978 ...
$ Region          : chr  "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK 
Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Prince William Sound" ...
$ Hatchery        : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "AF 
Koernig" ...
$ Project         : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Port San 
Juan" ...
$ Species         : chr  "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" ...
$ Seine           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " 2,000 " ...
$ Gillnet         : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ Troll           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ Other.Commercial: chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ Sport           : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ PersUse         : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ Subsis          : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " -   " ...
$ Brood           : chr  " 5,800 " " 8,000 " " -   " " 21,300 " ...
$ CR.catch        : chr  " -   " " -   " " -   " " 15,545 " ...
$ Other           : chr  " -   " " -   " " 18,500 " " -   " ...
```

If I use strip.white within the read.csv call, the white spaces are removed. I'm assuming this has something to do with how read.csv works, but looking through the appropriate [R documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) I still don't understand why this is occurring.

```
returns <-read.csv("~/R/ADFG_Obtained_AKReturns.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
str(returns)


'data.frame':   4222 obs. of  15 variables:
$ Year            : int  1975 1976 1977 1977 1977 1977 1977 1978 1978 
1978 ...
$ Region          : chr  "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK 
Peninsula" "Kodiak & AK Peninsula" "Prince William Sound" ...
$ Hatchery        : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "AF 
Koernig" ...
$ Project         : chr  "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Kitoi Bay" "Port San 
Juan" ...
$ Species         : chr  "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" "Pink" ...
$ Seine           : chr  "-" "-" "-" " 2,000 " ...
$ Gillnet         : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ Troll           : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ Other.Commercial: chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ Sport           : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ PersUse         : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ Subsis          : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
$ Brood           : chr  " 5,800 " " 8,000 " "-" " 21,300 " ...
$ CR.catch        : chr  "-" "-" "-" " 15,545 " ...
$ Other           : chr  "-" "-" " 18,500 " "-" ...
```

So adding the strip.white call does exactly what I would like for the blank ("-") cells, I just don't understand why; and why does trimws not work in this case?

Also, are there still whitespaces remaining on the observations that are numbers?

```
$ Seine           : chr  "-" "-" "-" " 2,000 " ...
```

For my next step, I will be changing the type from character to numeric with the following code, but would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this for all columns Seine:Other (cols 6:15 in my df).

```
returns$Seine <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",returns$Seine))

 $ Seine           : num  NA NA NA 2000 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

(FYI, this is the first question I have asked.)

Comment: Firstly, `trimws` doesn't work on a whole dataset at once. Secondly, you didn't overwrite `returns` after applying the function. R requires you to save over your old object. So `x + 1` does nothing to `x` but `x <- x + 1` will actually store the change back in `x`.

Comment: `returns=lapply(returns,trimws)`

Comment: @Onyambu - I think you mean `returns[] <- lapply(returns, trimws)` - slight difference but the `[]` ensures you keep the data.frame structure.

Comment: yes yes..  true true

Comment: Right, sorry about that, it was just a typo. Can you elaborate about how trimws doesn't work over an entire data set? I've had it work previously on a data set that had similar looking columns, but notice it wasn't working on this one, which I assumed was because of the different types of columns.

Comment: If your data was in a `matrix`, then `trimws` by itself would work, as in `trimws(matrix(' a ', nr=2, nc=2))`. But a frame is not as simple, so you need to do things column-wise, such as in Onyambu's comment-answer.